# Tensorflow 1.4 Bidirectional RNN not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, bidirectional, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to use Bidirectional RNN and pass the output through a CNN for text classification. However, I am getting all sorts of shape errors with bidirectional RNN. Although, If I use two dynamic rnn with reverse op in the second layer, it appears to work fine:

Here is bidirectional RNN code that DOES NOT work for me:

```
    # Bidirectional LSTM layer
    with tf.name_scope("bidirectional-lstm"):
        lstm_fw_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size, forget_bias=1.0)
        lstm_bw_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size, forget_bias=1.0)

        self.lstm_outputs, _ = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(
            lstm_fw_cell, 
            lstm_bw_cell, 
            self.embedded_chars, 
            sequence_length=self.seqlen, 
            dtype=tf.float32)
        self.lstm_outputs = tf.concat(self.lstm_outputs, axis=2)
```

Here is the two layer dynamic rnn that DOES work for me:

```
    # Bidirectional LSTM layer
    with tf.name_scope("bidirectional-lstm"):
        lstm_fw_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size, forget_bias=1.0)
        lstm_bw_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size, forget_bias=1.0)
    with tf.variable_scope("lstm-output-fw"):
        self.lstm_outputs_fw, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
            lstm_fw_cell, 
            self.embedded_chars, 
            sequence_length=self.seqlen, 
            dtype=tf.float32)

    with tf.variable_scope("lstm-output-bw"):
        self.embedded_chars_rev = array_ops.reverse_sequence(self.embedded_chars, seq_lengths=self.seqlen, seq_dim=1)
        tmp, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
            lstm_bw_cell, 
            self.embedded_chars_rev, 
            sequence_length=self.seqlen, 
            dtype=tf.float32)
        self.lstm_outputs_bw = array_ops.reverse_sequence(tmp, seq_lengths=self.seqlen, seq_dim=1)

    Concatenate outputs
    self.lstm_outputs = tf.add(self.lstm_outputs_fw, self.lstm_outputs_bw, name="lstm_outputs")
```

What am I doing wrong with bidirectional RNN ?

I am passing the output of this to CNN and error occurs when computing the

Here is the rest of the code:

```
# Convolution + maxpool layer for each filter size
        pooled_outputs = []
        for i, filter_size in enumerate(filter_sizes):
            with tf.name_scope("conv-maxpool-%s" % filter_size):
                # Convolution Layer
                filter_shape = [filter_size, hidden_size, 1, num_filters]
                W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(filter_shape, stddev=0.1), name="W")
                b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_filters]), name="b")

                conv = tf.nn.conv2d(
                    self.lstm_outputs_expanded, 
                    W,
                    strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], 
                    padding="VALID",
                    name="conv")

                # Apply nonlinearity
                h = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv, b), name="relu")

                # Maxpooling over the outputs
                pooled = tf.nn.max_pool(
                    h, 
                    ksize=[1, sequence_length - filter_size + 1, 1, 1],
                    strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], 
                    padding='VALID',
                    name="pool")
                pooled_outputs.append(pooled)

        # Combine all the pooled features
        num_filters_total = num_filters * len(filter_sizes)
        self.h_pool = tf.concat(axis=3, values=pooled_outputs)
        self.h_pool_flat = tf.reshape(self.h_pool, [-1, num_filters_total])


        # Dropout layer
        with tf.name_scope("dropout"):
            self.h_drop = tf.nn.dropout(self.h_pool_flat, self.dropout_keep_prob)


        # Final (unnormalized) scores and predictions
        with tf.name_scope("output"):
            # Standard output weights initialization
            W = tf.get_variable(
                "W", 
                shape=[num_filters_total, num_classes], 
                initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
            b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_classes]), name="b")

            # # Initialized output weights to 0.0, might improve accuracy
            # W = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[num_filters_total, num_classes]), name="W")
            # b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[num_classes]), name="b")

            l2_loss += tf.nn.l2_loss(W)
            l2_loss += tf.nn.l2_loss(b)

            self.scores = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(self.h_drop, W, b, name="scores")

            self.predictions = tf.argmax(self.scores, 1, name="predictions")

        # Calculate mean cross-entropy loss
        with tf.name_scope("loss"):
            losses = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=self.scores, labels=self.input_y)
            self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(losses) + l2_reg_lambda * l2_loss

        # Accuracy
        with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
            correct_predictions = tf.equal(self.predictions, tf.argmax(self.input_y, 1))
            self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predictions, "float"), name="accuracy")
```

And here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hemant/anaconda3/envs/tf14/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1323, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/hemant/anaconda3/envs/tf14/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1302, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/home/hemant/anaconda3/envs/tf14/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[7550,2] labels_size=[50,2]
         [[Node: loss/SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](loss/Reshape, loss/Reshape_1)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_upgraded.py", line 209, in <module>
    train_step(x_batch, seqlen_batch, y_batch)
  File "train_upgraded.py", line 177, in train_step
    feed_dict)
  File "/home/hemant/anaconda3/envs/tf14/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 889, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/hemant/anaconda3/envs/tf14/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1120, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/hemant/anaconda3/envs/tf14/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1317, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/hemant/anaconda3/envs/tf14/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1336, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[7550,2] labels_size=[50,2]
         [[Node: loss/SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](loss/Reshape, loss/Reshape_1)]]

Caused by op 'loss/SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits', defined at:
  File "train_upgraded.py", line 87, in <module>
    l2_reg_lambda=FLAGS.l2_reg_lambda)
  File "/media/hemant/MVV/MyValueVest-local/learning/Initial Embeddings/STEP 2 lstm-context-embeddings-master/model_upgraded.py", line 138, in __init__
    losses = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=self.scores, labels=self.input_y)
  File "/home/hemant/anaconda3/envs/tf14/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1783, in softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
    precise_logits, labels, name=name)
  File "/home/hemant/anaconda3/envs/tf14/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 4364, in _softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
    name=name)
  File "/home/hemant/anaconda3/envs/tf14/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/hemant/anaconda3/envs/tf14/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2956, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/hemant/anaconda3/envs/tf14/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1470, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[7550,2] labels_size=[50,2]
         [[Node: loss/SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](loss/Reshape, loss/Reshape_1)]]
```

Comment: Could you post the stack trace for the error?

Comment: Yes. Updated to include the rest of the code and the trace error message.

Comment: I think , the output shape of dynamic bidirectional RNN is slightly different than the dynamic rnn ? And I am having trouble reconciling the two...

Comment: what is the sequence length here I tried the same approach and set an seq len placeholder but not sure what to pass in it it throws InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'seqlen' with dtype int32 and shape [16]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was multiply the hidden size by 2 since output size of birrectional RNN is twice that of rnn.

```
filter_shape = [filter_size, hidden_size*2, 1, num_filters]3
```

Problem Solved.